# Joomla K2 change read more link in a duplicated module

Tags: php, joomla2.5, k2

i am working with Joomla 2.5 and K2, in a template i bought.

1st.
i got a an accordion module that display several items into the main page, when i click on any of its elements it redirects me to: http://uxmalrecordscom.ipower.com/index.php/component/k2/item/452-the-dream-master which is correct. (.../index.php/component/k2/item/...)

2nd.
I set this same module to appear into another page called Discography, and when i click in any of the accordion elements it sends me to: http://uxmalrecordscom.ipower.com/index.php/discography/item/452-the-dream-master this URL is different than the first one and is causing me issues to display the content of the Item. (.../index.php/discography/item/...)

My querstion is how can i change the URL for the second case the "Read more" links to avoid display the content of the item in the same page or main menu seccion? or how to make the 2nd to have this kind of URL (.../index.php/component/k2/item/...) instad of (.../index.php/discography/item/...)

Note: Its the same module used on 2 different pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this is to create a new Main Menu item called "Digital" then select as menu type = "K2 categories" and select the "Digital" category, this will cause all the K2 items listed under "Digital" displays on a different URL so now the url is (.../index.php/digital/item/...) instad of (.../index.php/discography/item/...) and is working awesome!

Hope this can help someone, this solved the problem to me.